# Markov Property of a Ito Process

Tags: analysis, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

*This is the excercise:*

**Let $B_t$ be 1d Brownian motion with $B_0=0$. Define**

$$
X_t=X_t^x=x\cdot\exp\left(ct+\alpha B_t\right)
$$

**where $c,\alpha$ are constants and $x$ is non-random. Prove directly from the definition that $X_t$ is a Markov process, i.e., that**

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(X_{t+h}\right)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=\mathbb{E}^{X_{t}}\left[f\left(X_{h}\right)\right]
$$

**for bounded Borel-measurable $f$.**

*Here is my attempt*

Let $\mathcal{F}_t^X:=\sigma\left(X_s:s\le t\right)$ and $\mathcal{F}_t^B:=\sigma\left(B_s:s\le t\right)$. Since $X_s$ is $\mathcal{F}_t^B$-measurable then $\mathcal{F}_t^X\subset\mathcal{F}_t^B$ we have, for any bounded Borel function $f(x)$,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}^x\left[f\left(X_{t+h}\right)\bigg|\mathcal{F}_t^X\right]&=\mathbb{E}^x\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp\left(c(t+h)+\alpha B_{t+h}\right)\right)\bigg|\mathcal{F}_t^X\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}^x\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp\left(c(t+h)+\alpha B_{t+h}\right)\right)\bigg|\mathcal{F}_t^B\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}^{B_t}\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp\left(c(t+h)+\alpha B_{t+h}\right)\right)\right]\in\sigma(B_t)=\sigma(X_t).
\end{aligned}
$$

So $\mathbb{E}^x\left[f\left(X_{t+h}\right)\bigg|\mathcal{F}_t^X\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(X_{t+h}\right)|X_t\right]$

Let $\mathcal{M}_t=\mathcal{F}_t^X:=\sigma\left(X_s:s\le t\right)$ and $\mathcal{F}_t=\mathcal{F}_t^B:=\sigma\left(B_s:s\le t\right)$. Since $X_s$ is $\mathcal{F}_t^B$-measurable then $\mathcal{F}_t^X\subset\mathcal{F}_t^B$ we have, for any bounded Borel function $f(x)$,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(X_{t+h}\right)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp\left(c(t+h)+\alpha B_{t+h}\right)\right)\bigg|\mathcal{F}_t\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp\left(ct+ch+\alpha B_{t+h}\pm\alpha B_{h}\right)\right)\bigg|\mathcal{F}_t\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp\left(ct+\alpha\left( B_{t+h}-B_{h}\right)+ch+\alpha B_{h}\right)\right)\bigg|\mathcal{F}_t\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp\left(ct+\alpha\left(B_{t+h}-B_{h}\right)\right)\exp\left(ch+\alpha B_{h}\right)\right)\bigg|\mathcal{F}_t\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Notice that $\hat{B_{t}}=B_{t+h}-B_{h}$ is a Brownian Motion and it is **equal in distribution** to $B_{t}$, so

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(X_{t+h}\right)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp\left(ct+\alpha\left(B_{t+h}-B_{h}\right)\right)\exp\left(ch+\alpha B_{h}\right)\right)\bigg|\mathcal{F}_t\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(\exp\left(ct+\alpha\hat{B_{t}} \right)\cdot x\cdot\exp\left(ch+\alpha B_{h}\right)\right)\bigg|\sigma\left(B_s:s\le t\right)\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(\exp\left(ct+\alpha\hat{B_{t}} \right)X_h\right)\bigg|\sigma\left(B_s:s\le t\right)\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(\exp\left(ct+\alpha B_t \right)X_h\right)\bigg|\sigma\left(B_s:s\le t\right)\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp\left(ct+\alpha B_t \right)\cdot\exp\left(ch+\alpha B_{h}\right)\right)\bigg|\sigma\left(B_s:s\le t\right)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

And at the same time, if we where to start at $y=X_t=x\cdot\exp(ct+\alpha B_t)$, we would have that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}^{X_{t}}\left[f\left(X_{h}\right)\right]&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(y\cdot\exp\left(ch+\alpha B_{h}\right)\right)\right]\bigg|_{y=X_t}\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp(ct+\alpha B_t)\cdot\exp\left(ch+\alpha B_{h}\right)\right)\bigg|X_t\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp(ct+\alpha B_t)\cdot\exp\left(ch+\alpha B_{h}\right)\right)\bigg|\sigma\left(X_s:s\le t\right)\right].
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $\sigma(X_t)=\sigma(B_t)$, we have that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}^{X_{t}}\left[f\left(X_{h}\right)\right]&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(y\cdot\exp\left(ch+\alpha B_{h}\right)\right)\right]\bigg|_{y=X_t}\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp(ct+\alpha B_t)\cdot\exp\left(ch+\alpha B_{h}\right)\right)\bigg|\sigma\left(X_s:s\le t\right)\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(x\cdot\exp(ct+\alpha B_t)\cdot\exp\left(ch+\alpha B_{h}\right)\right)\bigg|\sigma\left(B_s:s\le t\right)\right].
\end{aligned}
$$

In other words, we have just prove that

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(X_{t+h}\right)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=\mathbb{E}^{X_{t}}\left[f\left(X_{h}\right)\right].
$$

**Could anyone please check if my reasoning is correct? Thanks**